# Redirecionamento página de login não corresponde

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com dificuldade em redirecionar o usuário após o login.

Preciso de um auxílio, para encontrar a solução.

valida_user_login.php

```html
<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$banco = 'bd_';
// Conecta-se ao banco de dados MySQL
$con = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
// Check conexão
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 
// Muda o bd
mysqli_select_db($con,"bd_");

//insere os dados recebidos pelo formulario
$email_cad = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email_cad']);
$senha_cad = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['senha_cad']);

// Verifica se houve POST e se o usuário ou a senha é(são) vazio(s)
if (empty($_POST)){
 header("Location: pg_login.php"); 
 exit;
}
$sql = "SELECT INTO usuarios (email_cad, senha_cad) VALUES ('$email_cad', '$senha_cad')";

$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row != 1) {
    // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
    header("Location: pg_login.php"); exit;
  } else {
     // Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
      $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
     if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
      session_start();
      // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
      $_SESSION['email_cad'] = $resultado['email_cad'];
      // Redireciona o visitante
      header("Location: pg_resultado.php"); exit;
    }else{
        header("Location: pg_cadastro.php"); 
    }
   }
 }
}
$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Ta mto estranho esse código, `select into` é usado normalmente para copiar dados de uma tabela para uma nova. Isso deveria ser um select normal como um `WHERE` se vai retornar apenas um registro não precisa de while, pode usar o limit se quiser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<?php
session_start();
$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$banco = 'bd_';
// Conecta-se ao banco de dados MySQL
$con = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
// Check conexão
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 
// Muda o bd
mysqli_select_db($con,"bd_");

//insere os dados recebidos pelo formulario
$email_cad = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email_cad']);
$senha_cad = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['senha_cad']);

// Verifica se houve POST e se o usuário ou a senha é(são) vazio(s)
if (empty($_POST)){
 header("Location: pg_login.php"); 
 exit;
}
$sql = "SELECT INTO usuarios (email_cad, senha_cad) VALUES ('$email_cad', '$senha_cad')";

$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row != 1) {
    // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
    header("Location: pg_login.php"); exit;
  } else {
     // Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
      $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION['logado'] = $resultado;
     // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
     if ($_SESSION['logado']==false) {

     // Redireciona o visitante
      header("Location: pg_resultado.php"); exit;
    }else{
        header("Location: pg_cadastro.php"); 
    }
   }
 }
}
$con->close();
?>
```

Eu faria desta forma, modificando e criando as sessions, depois do Login, na página do usuário logado, dê um session_start() no começo dele, e um print_r($_SESSION['logado']); e recupere os resultados.